# Getting slimes to spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make a slime farm, but I can't get slimes to spawn. I've found the Slime chucks, I'm below level 40, I have a 3 high room, I know it's a slime chuck because when I place a mob spawner to place slimes they spawn, the spawner does nothing in a no-slime chuck.

Do slimes need anything else to spawn other than under 40, and in a 3 high room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slimes have the same mob cap as other mobs, so they won't spawn very frequently if there are a lot of unlit caves around. To get good rates, light up all caves at least in a 30 block radius (150 blocks for perfect rates), and make sure the room itself is lit up. Slimes spawn in lit areas underground, and that will keep the other mobs from spawning.

Another tip: create multiple levels in the slime chunk, and you'll get tons  more slimes!

Comment: I'm gonna do the multiple levels when I get it working :P. when digging out the area I ran in to LOADS of caves, so I'll go fill em in/light em up, cheers!

Comment: Good! Let me know if that works.

Comment: +1 for the multiple levels, I've been trying to get slimes to spawn for ages. I'd dug a 16x16 slime chunk from about level 40 to level 12 and didn't see a single spawn. Decided to add some extra floors every five blocks down, and I started seeing slimes spawn, so thanks for the tip.